# using different development environments in database.yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to have a single database.yaml as part of a project two separate teams are working on. While the test and production sections are the same, the development section is different for the two teams. Is there a way I can do this using a local environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own configuration mechanism (e.g., per-user, per-machine, etc.) or just create a new configuration and set it via `RAILS_ENV`:

```
RAILS_ENV=dev1 rails s # Or rails c etc, to run the "other" dev config...
RAILS_ENV=dev2 rails s
```

Comment: I assume that this would have the side effect of creating a dev1.log, dev2.log, etc?